# Android app not searchable in play store 10 days after being published

Tags: android, google-play

So I published my app into the Play Store 10 days ago. Although a link to the actual app page works, manually searching for either the app or the app developer (me) doesn't bring my app up. How long does it take for a new app to become searchable?

EDIT: Here is a link to my app in the Play Store:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nasah.grades

And here is my manifest file, just in case I got something wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.nasah.grades"
      android:versionCode="3"
      android:versionName="1.1">

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"/>
```

The rest of my manifest are `<activity>` tags.

Comment: What kind of device have you tried for the search? Check the list of the supported devices to see if yours is there!

Comment: I have tried searching from my phone (Galaxy Nexus), my tablet (Nexus 7), and from the desktop at play.google.com. I'm surprised at how after updating my app 3 times in the span of the last 10 days, all 3 updates are pushed through but yet I CAN'T EVEN SEARCH FOR MY APP!

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make any edit at your manifest? You probably have made something to restrict some devices at Play Google developer area!

Comment: The only devices my app is not compatible with are Google TV devices. Otherwise, my app  is compatible with phones of all sizes and tablets of all sizes, according to Google in their device compatibility list for my app. Regardless of the device, my app should be found via the play store on a computer, right? Even if I'm not logged on to a Google account, searching through the play store should search for my app regardless.

Comment: can you link us your app on play store?

Comment: Made an edit including link and manifest

Comment: I searched "nasah grades" & I found the app. I have a Nexus 4.

Comment: Then why does searching just "nasah" or just "grades" NOT bring it up? I've literally searched and went through every page of results using just nasah or grades

Comment: I'm having the following message on browser: "This item cannot be installed in your device's country". Have you limited the distribution to some countries?

Comment: Yes, what country are you trying to install from?

Answer (score 1):

Note that even when you use the exact app title as search term your app is sometimes listed 400 lines below other listed apps. This is really ridiculous. Maybe apps get listed based on their ranking.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar difficulty just today; 3 days after releasing to production I still couldn't find my app. However, the Play store url also wasn't working. I navigated back to my developer console and noticed that my app was in Alpha rather than production. Perhaps this is something you can check.